# Using SQL from Excel definition in Python?

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

I already have a Python script that converts my Excel table into a dataframe using pandas and does all the needed work with that dataframe. The Excel table is being generated by SQL code (about 70 lines) that you can see in Command text window under Connections:Properties:Definition in Excel. Since the data is not static, I am wondering if I can use the same SQL code in my Python script to have fresh data I ran the script. Could somebody please advise how I can have my Python script to generate the same dataframe using the same SQL code?

Comment: `pandas.read_sql('SQL',connection)` will read your sql statement directly into a DataFrame. You need to give more specifics if you want a proper answer.

Comment: A quick google search would give you answer you're looking for.

Comment: How do I enter 70 lines of SQL code into this format pandas.read_sql('SQL',connection)? Should I create a separate file with that code and have pandas.read_sql read it?